# Post Data to html page listen by java script method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html page, where I have a method which work in set interval

```
window.setInterval(updateMake, 2000);
function updateMake() {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
}
```

Where `a` and `b` are global variable on html page.

I want to update this a and be from different pages.
like posting two values on this page. and this page should have any listener which fetch posted values and update a and b.

Can someone guide me any way.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds a bit like you want [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: You can use HTML5 local storage technique.

Comment: `setInterval` is a bad choice.!!!! it can cause raise condition. use `setTimeout` instead

Comment: postMessage sounds good, Thanks heard first time

Answer (score 0):

here an [example](http://output.jsbin.com/ducomivaqo), it set parent window variable using like `window.opener.myVar`

parent window

```
<input type="button" value="open Tab" onclick="openTab()">
<p>Message: <span id="setMessage">...</id></p>

<script>
setTimeout(updateMake, 1000);

var setMessage = ''
function updateMake(){
  document.getElementById('setMessage').innerHTML = setMessage;
  setTimeout(updateMake, 1000);
}

function openTab(){
   window.open("http://output.jsbin.com/cofojamige");
}
```

child window

```
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="sendMessage" onclick="sendMessage()">

<script>
function sendMessage(){
  window.opener.setMessage = document.getElementById('message').value;
}
</script>
```